# read sprite css always in fullscreen size?

Tags: css, css-animations, sprite, css-sprites

I try to animate a sprite with auto fullscreen size
[image: https://ibb.co/k2a0fe]

but I don't know how can I do to read this sprite always in fullscreen (i.e. 100% of width and height of screen, and auto adapte if resizing)

any idea to autosize sprite ?

```css
@-moz-keyframes play {
  0% {
    background-position: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 100%;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes play {
  0% {
    background-position: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes play {
  0% {
    background-position: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 100%;
  }
}

#loader
{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999999999999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/hCqoYz/preloader_bg_bw2.png);
  background-size: 1100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-animation: play 2s infinite steps(11);
  -moz-animation: play 2s infinite steps(11);
  -o-animation: play 2s infinite steps(11);
  animation: play 2s infinite steps(11);
}
```

```html
<div id="loader"></div>
```

Comment: you are obliged to keep a ratio you cannot have your sprite 100% height and 100% width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there!
There should be `steps(10)` as the start position is not a step actually.

BTW, `z-index: 999999999999` looks paranoid to me =)).

```css
@keyframes play {
  100% {
    background-position: 100%;
  }
}

#loader
{
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  top: 0; right:0;
  bottom:0; left: 0;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/hCqoYz/preloader_bg_bw2.png);
  background-size: 1100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation: play 1s infinite steps(10);
}
```

```html
<div id="loader"></div>
```

**Update**
Question bonus:

```css
@keyframes play {
  99.99% {
    background-position: 120%;
    background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/hCqoYz/preloader_bg_bw2.png);
  }
  100% {
    background-image: none;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  
}

#loader {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-image: url(https://image.ibb.co/hCqoYz/preloader_bg_bw2.png);
  background-size: 1100% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation: play 2s steps(12) forwards;
}

body {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/640/480) 50% 50% /cover
```

```html
<div id="loader"></div>
```

Comment: oh shit ! steps number is not nb of frames but nb frames -1? ^^ I was almost there, indeed ! Question BONUS : how can we delete background at end of animation, without javascript?

Comment: For question bonus : I finaly add another css animation (with delay) to change height to 0 and opacity to 0, otherwise the div stay with z-index superior to the web site and can't interact with it...