# how can we "inline sprite image"?

Tags: css, animation, sprite, css-sprites, sprite-sheet

[image]

There is tool or method to *inline* sprite animation ?

I need all steps of this animation was on same "line" (i.e. fixed height of image to 313px in my exemple)

Why I want to do that : it's more simple to animate it in CSS : need only to change background-x position

**how can we "inline this sprite" ?**

Comment: [Twitter Heart Animation](https://css-tricks.com/recreating-the-twitter-heart-animation/) will help you to understand the process, Yeah! Changing background-x position in sprite animation make easy and the tutorial also say same things.

Comment: I know already how it works, see here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51663619/read-sprite-css-always-in-fullscreen-size